# Issues with resolution of SDL window/texture in android phones

Tags: android, sdl

I am trying to stream video over RTSP protocol in Android phones. I have created an application that receive packets over RTSP protocol, decode using FFMPEG, and present it to the window using SDL 2.0. In that application, creating the SDL window and SDL texture looks like this:

```
screen = SDL_CreateWindow ("Test ffmpeg",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN|SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN ); 

bmp = SDL_CreateTexture  (renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_IYUV, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 1280, 720);
```

This application runs smoothly (without any flickering or distortions) on Samsung Galaxy S3 (but with reddish overlay), but on HTC sensation xe, samsung galaxy grand, sony xperia S, there is a lot of flickering and distortions. When I tried to reduce the resolution in both of the above functions (i.e) creating texture and creating window (640*360 in HTC sensation xe and 800*480 in samsung galaxy grand), the application runs smoothly. Now I have two questions

1. Why mobiles other than samsung galaxy s3 (out of all the mobiles mentioned above) unable to stream video of higher resolution (1280*720)?
2. On all samsung galaxy s3 mobiles, I can see a reddish overlay. Anybody have any idea what is the cause of that reddish overlay?

Comment: Re 2, see https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2291 it's a known "bug", there's a workaround listed there.
Also, FWIW, SDL2 for Android ignores whatever window size you request and uses the native resolution of the display.

Answer (score 2):

Re 2, I have solved the reddish display issue on samsung galaxy s3 mobiles by disabling the hardware overlay option in the developer options menu (Settings->Developer Options->Check the "disable hardware overlay" checkbox)